# How to filter a elements of matrixes?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to get some pixel values from an image which are not equal with a specified value. But I want to get back in RGB format and not as a long vector. How can I do it?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
sought = [36,255,12]
result = image[image!=sought]

import sys
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
print(result)
```

And I've got:

```
  [20 103  75  21  98  70  16 100  72  18 101  73  19  97  69  15  95  66
  15  95  67  13 101  73  19 104  77  21  96  69  13  94  65   8  99  69
  14  98  68  13  94  63  10  88  66  24  92  69  24  92  67  23  93  67
  13  93  67  13  93  67  13  97  72  16  96  70  16  93  66  15  96  68
  .....
  99  69  14  96  66  11  91  67  25  88  65  20  92  68  14  96  69  18
  96  70  16  91  64  13  95  67  13  92  64  10  90  63]
```

But I want something like this:

```
     [[[R,G,B], [R,G,B], [R,G,B], [R,G,B]],
       ......
      [[R,G,B], [R,G,B], [R,G,B], [R,G,B]]]
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: Hey ! Not sure to understand the output shape you are looking for. Do you want a list of pixels (thus shape (n, 3)) ? Why is your desired output a (n,m, 3) array ?

Comment: what you want is logically impossible. you are looking for individual pixels with your comparison. they will no longer have any spatial relationship to each other. show what you _really_ want to do. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @PlainRavioli the list of pixels if the pixel is a 3 element array then it's also good to me, just I want each pixel in separate sub array.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I want to get the intensity on each remaining pixel on each color chanel without having trouble with a specific color. This make sense, because this is how I will remove specific noise on my image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the wanted output is a list of pixels, then after the component-wise comparison, you must check what pixels differ on any of the R,G or B with `.any(axis = 2)`:

```
image[(image != sought).any(axis=2)]
```

output of the form:

```
array([[ 22, 136, 161],
       [197, 141, 153],
       [173, 122,  65],
       [137, 189,  67],
             ...
       [166, 205, 238],
       [207,  99, 129],
       [ 44,  76,  97]])
```

Answer (score 2):

With `result = image[image != sought]` you lost the shape of `image`.
The solution is to get a mask (`image != sought`) and work on the image with that mask (e.g. using `np.where`)

Generate some data:

```py
import numpy as np

H, W, C = 8, 8, 3
sought = [255, 0, 0]
colors = np.array(
    [sought, [0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0], [0, 255, 255], [255, 0, 255], [255, 255, 0]]
)
colors_idxs = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(colors)), size=(H, W))
image = colors[colors_idxs]
```

Compute mask (note the `keepdims=True` for `np.where` to work easier):

```py
mask = np.any(image != sought, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

# Get color back into the mask
mask_inpaint_pos = np.where(mask, image, 0)
mask_inpaint_neg = np.where(mask, 0, image)
```

Plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax_im, ax_mask, ax_mask_pos, ax_mask_neg) = plt.subplots(ncols=4, sharey=True)

ax_im.set_title("Original")
ax_im.imshow(image)

ax_mask.set_title("Mask binary")
ax_mask.imshow(mask.astype(int), cmap="gray")

ax_mask_pos.set_title("Mask True RGB")
ax_mask_pos.imshow(mask_inpaint_pos)

ax_mask_neg.set_title("Mask False RGB")
ax_mask_neg.imshow(mask_inpaint_neg)

plt.show()
```

[image: orig / mask / masks rgb]

Comment: Thanks for helping me @paime But now on `mask_inpaint_pos` there are still all of those pixel values which was removed, with [0, 0, 0]. Is that possible to get only the remaining pixels?

Comment: You either get a list of pixels with `image[image != sought]` as you did, or if you want to keep the array's shape then you need something to fill the holes, they can't just be empty. What do you want to achieve ? If this is related to plots, go from RGB to RGBA and set alpha channel accordingly to the mask.